# Optuna hyperparameter search repeats hyperparameters across studies with parallelization

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, hyperparameters, optuna

In order to speed the training up, I've implemented easy parallelization with my networks in Optuna, as can be seen in the video in the official documentation of Optuna: https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/004_distributed.html For the study optimization, I'm using the TPESampler, as it's also Optuna's default.

However, with parallelization in essence we have multiple studies (in my case, 4 as I have 4 GPUs in the environment), which have repeating values of hyperparameters among those studies.

**Expected:** different hyperparameter values between given studies in parallel

**Actual**: parameters repeat between studies

As an example, here is a sample of my run of 4 studies in parallel each 20 trials on 400 epochs (note the repeating hyperparameters between studies, not just the first few):

Run 1: https://pastebin.com/qQ4EzZQH

Run 2: https://pastebin.com/gMq9CHGr

Run 3: https://pastebin.com/FUnAjM52

Run 4: https://pastebin.com/fBSkGGmK

Since TPESampler chooses next hyperparameters based on the results of the previous hyperparameters, it does not make much sense to have hyperparameters repeat between studies, but rather upgrade. So, for example, in a study of 80 consecutive trials without parallelization, on each next trial the values of hyperparameters would "adjust", but here with parallelization, the values repeat.

**Minimal working example:**

```
import optuna
import sys

def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_float("x", -10, 10)
    return (x - 4) ** 2

def main_optuna():
    num_trials = 20
    study = optuna.create_study(study_name = "data-params-optimization3-", 
                                direction="minimize",
                                storage='sqlite:///trials.db', 
                                sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=17),
                                load_if_exists=True)
                                
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=num_trials)


    pruned_trials = [t for t in study.trials if t.state == optuna.structs.TrialState.PRUNED]
    complete_trials = [t for t in study.trials if t.state == optuna.structs.TrialState.COMPLETE]

    print("Study statistics: ")
    print("  Number of finished trials: ", len(study.trials))
    print("  Number of pruned trials: ", len(pruned_trials))
    print("  Number of complete trials: ", len(complete_trials))

    print("Best trial:")
    trial = study.best_trial

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_optuna()
```

Running the studies is the same as in the Optuna official documentation, meaning starting it from 4 different terminals with:

`python optuna.py`

**Relevant environment:**

4 Nvidia A100 GPUs

**Additional info**

What I've also tried is setting the `n_startup_trials=3` argument in TPESampler, but the parameters repeat after 3 random trials.

**Question**

Is there any way to optimize hyperparameters across studies which run in parallel in Optuna using TPESampler, where the sampler learns from all studies and does not repeat values?

Comment: The suggested params would likely be the same among studies if the objective value is time-consuming and each TPE sampler uses the same random seed. This is because each TPE suggests new hyperparameters based on __the same complete trials__ with __the same random  seed__. So the solution would be to set different random seed of TPE among studies.

Comment: @nzw0301 Thank you for the insight. I do have a time consuming objective function, hence my trials are limited (usually max. 80). That's precisely why I was wondering if I could somehow use the other hyperparameter values and have one run equal to, say, 80 TPE optimizations rather than 20 separate TPE optimizations on 4 different studies.